# Is "whatever is left can <verb>" correct grammar?

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement, verb-stacking

> Whatever is left can be given away.

Initially this seems like a complete sentence, but it seems odd to me that the verb phase involving "is" is used as a subject. Could someone explain why or why not this is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Whatever is left" is a noun *clause* with Subject-Verb-Complement order.  That clause serves as the subject of the independent clause that has "can be given" as its verb.